# Google Sheets Script: TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've had this script running for over a year just fine for a shared sheet: it basically clears all the input fields in the new sheet whenever you duplicate a sheet. For some reason it stopped working last week and keep throwing the above error message; I can't seem to figure out what happened. The error seems to be on the changetype in the initial "if" function. Appreciate any insights!

Here is the script:

```
function newSheet(e) {
  if(e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID') {

      //clear finance columns 
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AT20:AU31').clearContent();      
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AW20:AX31').clearContent();      
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AU44:AU46').clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AU54:AU58').clearContent();

      //clear Ops rows
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C58:AS61').clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C71:AS73').clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C80:AS90').clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C99:AS101').clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C114:AS116').clearContent();

      //clear FX movement rows
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D133:D144').clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G133:G144').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('M133:M144').clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('P133:P144').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AE133:AE144').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AH133:AH144').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AN133:AN144').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G149:G158').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J149:J158').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('M149:M158').clearContent();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('P149:P158').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('S149:S158').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('V149:V158').clearContent();        
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Y149:Y158').clearContent();            
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AB149:AB158').clearContent();            
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AE149:AE158').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AH149:AH158').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AK149:AK158').clearContent();          
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AN149:AN158').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AQ149:AQ158').clearContent();        
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('V164:V172').clearContent();        
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Y164:Y172').clearContent();            
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AB164:AB172').clearContent();            
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AE164:AE172').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AH164:AH172').clearContent();    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AK164:AK172').clearContent();      


      //set Ops checks to 'Not Done'
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C63:O63').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA63').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AG63:AJ63').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AM63:AN63').setValue('Not Done');    
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E65:L65').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('S65').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AN65').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AD75:AG75').setValue('Not Done');  
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F75:L75').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O75:S75').setValue('Not Done');      
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G77:L77').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('S77').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C103:D103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O103:P103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R103:S103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U103:V103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('X103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AD103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AG103:AH103').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AJ103').setValue('Not Done');  
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AM103').setValue('Not Done');  
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AP103').setValue('Not Done');  
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O106:P106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R106:S106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U106:V106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('X106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AD106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AG106:AH106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AJ106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AM106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AP106').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R118').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('U118').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('X118').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AA118').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AD118').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AG118').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AJ118').setValue('Not Done');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('AM118').setValue('Not Done');
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: 'e' is not defined. where does the 'newSheet' function get called? The 'e' argument it is passing is not valid apparently. (e probably means 'event'.) The problem is probably not with the function you have shared, it is with the function before it.

Comment: If your running it on V8 try switching back to the old runtime.

Comment: @DanOswalt I have a trigger running which calls the 'newSheet' function whenever there is a change to the spreadsheet. I have tried removing the previous function and the same error arises

Comment: @Cooper thanks for the suggestion, tried it and I'm getting the same error

Comment: What kind of a change causes a type insert_grid?

Comment: I’m not sure about this but I think the changes have to come from user actions and not script actions

Comment: So ```e``` is referred to the event? What type of trigger are you using? Have you installed it adecuately? Are you seen the logs of this trigger in the right way using ```console.log()```?

Comment: This doesn't run in browser, to print to debug console you would use Logger.log (if I recall).